# Is it possible to dismissModalViewController using XCode 4.2 storyboards?

Tags: ios5

With the storyboards, it is really easy to presentModalViewController but I didn't find a way to dismissModalViewController. Is there a way to do it ? Or do I need to do it through the code ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 5 the preferred new way to do this is to use the more powerful

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```